# Can you verify this proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

I'm a freshman in college and my professor challenged us to find a proof of this theorem. Please don't give me the answer but please verify if this proof works or, if not, if it is the start of a proof that needs to be filled in, or if you think I should abandon this line of thought. If it doesn't work, please explain why. This is kind of a sketch of a proof, really, and (I think) it uses the axiom of choice which I don't like, but it's a start. (I'm not sure if it actually uses the AoC. Does it?)

> Theorem: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ be injections. Then there is a bijection from $A$ onto $B$.
>
> > Lemma: Let A and B be sets such that there is no bijection from A onto B. Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ be injections. Then there is at least one element $x\in A$ such that $f(x)\not= g^{-1}(x)$.
> >
> > Proof: By contradiction. Assume that $f(a)=g^{-1}(a)$ for every $a\in A$ where $g^{-1}(a)$ is defined. Either $A=g[B]$ or $g[B]\subset A$ (strictly contained). If $g[B] = A$, then $f=g^{-1}$ and $f$ is a bijection, which is a contradiction. So $g[B]\subset A$. But since $g^{-1}$ is a surjection, every element of $B$ is mapped to an element of $A$, so for any $x\in A-g[B]$, $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $y\in g[B]$ and $f$ is not injective, which is a contradiction.
>
> proof of theorem: By contradiction. Assume there is no bijection from $A$ onto $B$.
>
> By the lemma, since f and g are injections, there must be a $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\not=g^{-1}(a)$. Similarly, there must be a $b\in B$ such that $g(b)\not=f^{-1}(b)$.
>   Let $A'$ and $B'$ be the subsets of A and B where $a\in A',b\in B'$ iff $f(a)\not=g^{-1}(a), g(b)\not= f^{-1}(b)$
>
> Define $h:A\to B$ where 
>   $$h(x)=f(x)$$ whenever $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ 
>   and $$h(a)=b $$where $a$ is some element of $ A'$ and $b$ is some element of $ B'$.
>
> Clearly, $h:A-A'\to B-B'$ is a bijection, since $f=g^{-1}$ is a bijection.
>
> Also, $h:A'\to B'$ is a bijection because

And then something about how there is always a $d\in B'$ for any $c\in A'$, meaning they come in pairs, but then we can define $h(c)=d$ and get our bijection again.

> So $h:A\to B$ is a bijection, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Your definition of $h$ on $A'$ is dubious at best, and definitely requires AC. What I think you are trying to say is that assuming $A'$ and $B'$ are well-ordered and so indexed by ordinals, define $h(a_{\alpha})=b_{\alpha}$ where $a_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-least element of $A'$ and similarly for $b_{\alpha}$. If this process finishes with $A'$ and $B'$ running out of elements at the same time, then you have a bijection, and if not, your "they come in pairs" argument may be able to deduce a contradiction.

Comment: I would also refactor your "lemma" to say that $h:A-A'\to B-B'$ is a bijection (there is no particular need to prove that $A'$ and $B'$ are nonempty, because you are trying to prove that $h$ is a bijection so if they are empty then you are done already).

Comment: "your 'they come in pairs' argument may be able to deduce a contradiction."   

Can you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: On second thought, I don't think that your otherwise-unstructured definition of $h$ on the sets $A',B'$ will give you anything useful, since its definition is not related to either $f$ or $g$, so knowing that, say, $g(b)\ne f^{-1}(b)$ for some $b\in B'\setminus h[A]$ (if we suppose that $A'$ runs out of elements before $B'$ doesn't lead anywhere. And since that's the core of the proof, I would be inclined to abandon this approach altogether. If you are comfortable with assuming AC, there is actually a much simpler argument along similar lines, which I will put in an answer.

Comment: Thank you, but Please don't post an answer. I'm more interested in finding it myself than knowing how it's done.

Comment: Note that neither the answer I've posted nor your argument is the "standard" proof, which is rather tricky and IMO hard to come up with independently. Don't worry, I won't spoil the fun of your next class ;)

Comment: Adding this here so I don't forget, I think it's worth noting that 1) $A'\cup B'$ is closed under any composition of f, g, or their inverses which means 2) $f:A'\to B'$ is an injection, and so is $g:B'\to A'$. Not sure if that's good for anything.

Comment: And trivially, since 2 is true, there's at least one element in $x\in A'$ such that $f(x)\not= g^{-1}(x)$ ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with using AC, then there is the argument which boils down to "$|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\le|A|$ so $|A|=|B|$". Unpacking all the notation and hidden lemmas leads to the following:

An ordinal is a transitive set well-ordered by the $\in$ relation, and it is not difficult to prove that there are a proper class of ordinals, and the class of ordinals is itself well-ordered by $\in$. Assuming the well-ordering theorem, which is an AC equivalent, given any set $A$ we can find a well-ordering $R$ of $A$, and the order type of $R$ is an ordinal $\alpha$, which is then in bijection with $A$. Thus the class of all ordinals in bijection with $A$ is nonempty, so there is a unique least such ordinal, and we define this to be $|A|$, the cardinal of $A$. (Note that AC is not needed to define cardinals, but only to show that every set is associated with a cardinal.)

Since ordinals are totally ordered, we have a much simpler theory of set sizes in this context. First let's show:

> Lemma: If $A\subseteq \alpha$ is a set of ordinals contained in an ordinal $\alpha$, then $|A|\le\alpha$.
>
> Proof: Since $A$ is well-ordered by $\epsilon$ (as a set of ordinals), we can define a bijection $f$ by letting the $\beta$ be mapped to the $\beta$-smallest element of $A$ (more precisely: define $f$ by transfinite recursion so that $f(\beta)=\min(A\setminus f[\beta])$, which is to say, set $f(\beta)$ to be the smallest element of $A$ which is not $f(\gamma)$ for any $\gamma<\beta$). This process terminates eventually, because $A$ is a set, and the result is a bijection from some ordinal $\kappa$ to $A$.
>
> Since $f$ is a strictly increasing ordinal function, we in fact have $f(\beta)\ge\beta$ (which can be proven by transfinite induction), so $\alpha\ge\sup_{\beta<\kappa}f(\beta)\ge\sup_{\beta<\kappa}\beta=\kappa$, and since $\kappa$ is in bijection with $A$, $|A|\le\kappa\le\alpha$ as desired.

And now we are nearly done. If $f:A\to B$ is an injection, then letting $i:B\to|B|$ be a bijection, $i\circ f:A\to|B|$ is an injection and $i\circ f[A]$ is a set of ordinals contained in $|B|$, so by the lemma, $|i\circ f[A]|\le|B|$, and since $i\circ f$ is also a bijection between $A$ and $i\circ f[A]$, $|A|=|i\circ f[A]|\le|B|$.

And now we can proceed along the lines mentioned at the beginning. If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are bijections, then $|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\le|A|$, so since ordinals are totally ordered, $|A|=|B|$, and so there is a bijection from $|A|=|B|$ to $A$ and to $B$, which we can compose to get a bijection from $A$ to $B$. (Reminder: this proof requires AC, but only in order to ensure that $|A|$ and $|B|$ are defined. It still works without AC if you assume that $A$ and $B$ are well-orderable.)

Comment: Isn't your lemma proved by noting that the identity function is an injection from $A$ to $\alpha$, and therefore $|A|\leq|\alpha|\leq\alpha$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The whole point is to show that an injection implies inequality of cardinals. Since cardinals are defined in terms of bijections, it is not *a priori* obvious.

Comment: If cardinals are defined in terms of bijections, what does it mean $|A|\leq\alpha$? Since $\alpha$ is an ordinal. If cardinals are, while defined by bijections, considered to be initial ordinals (which are ordinals which are not in bijection with any of their members), then you just need the trivial lemma, $|\alpha|\leq\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The cardinal $|A|$ is the smallest ordinal in bijection with $A$. It is an ordinal, so $|A|\le\alpha$ means $|A|\in\alpha$, i.e. this is the ordinal ordering. I am not making direct reference to initial ordinals here, but it is easy to see that $|A|$ is an initial ordinal, because if $\alpha<|A|$ then by minimality of $|A|$, $\alpha$ is not in bijection with $A$ and hence not in bijection with $|A|$ either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How do you propose to assert $|A|\le|\alpha|$ given $A\subseteq\alpha$ in the lemma? All I know from the definition is that $|A|$ is less than any ordinals it is in bijection with, and it may not be in bijection with $\alpha$, only injection. That's why I construct $\kappa$, because it is known to be in bijection with $A$ so that we can get an inequality with $|A|$ out of it.

Comment: (1) $|A|\in\alpha$ means necessarily that $|A|<\alpha$. I'm sure it's a typo on your side, though, just for 3rd party readers not to be confused. (2) It is a bad bad *bad* idea to use $\leq$ both for ordinals and cardinals, before establishing that $|A|\leq|B|$ is the same for both. If cardinals are defined by bijections, their order is defined by injections, in which case it is again trivial that $|A|\leq|\alpha|$. Now by your definition of minimality, it is even simpler that $|\alpha|\leq\alpha$, since $\alpha$ has a bijection with itself, so the least such ordinal is definitely not larger.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah okay, I see. At no point in this post do I use the notation $|A|\le|B|$ to mean "there is an injection from $A$ to $B$", it always means "the ordinal $|A|$ is less than or equal to the ordinal $|B|$". The goal is to show that if there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ then $|A|\le|B|$, and the converse is trivial.

Comment: (FWIW, If I wanted a notation for "there is an injection from $A$ to $B$", I would use $A\preceq B$, as I find the notation $|A|\le|B|$ that you are referring to too easy to misread or abuse, especially in non-AC contexts.)

Comment: Au contraire, in non-AC contexts it's quite clear that $|A|$ is a cardinal, which may or may not be an ordinal. And since for initial ordinals $|A|\leq|B|$ is not ambiguous (after you've proved that they are the same thing, of course), it's really fine.